# Which attribute triggered my CRM 4.0 workflow

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm

I have a CRM 4.0 workflow with a custom workflow activity. This workflow is triggered on select attribute updates of accounts. The selected attributes is a list of 20-30 fields. Is there a way to find which attributes triggered the workflow in CRM 4.0 (i.e. attributes have changed) without creating a separate workflow for each attribute or using auditing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workflow is really just a fancy asynchronous plugin. This article has a great explanation: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2009/06/24/microsoft-dynamics-crm-4-0-iworkflowcontext-interface.aspx

Notice you can access the InputParameters collection from the workflow context. This should contain your TargetEntity just like in normal plugin programming. The TargetEntity will only contain fields that changed, so you can loop through that collection to discover which field updates triggered the workflow.